# CentOS Installation stuck at "started hardware RNG entropy"

Tags: centos, software-installation, hardware

I have a HP Proliant G9 server which i wanted to install CentOS 7.5 on it. this server is completely new and there was nothing on it before. when i mounted the CentOS ISO file and rebooted the server, the installation started but is stuck:

```
  [ok] reached target basic system.
       starting login service...
       .
       .
  [ok] started hardware RNG Entropy Ga therer Daemon.
  -
```

I used this ISO image on another 2 server and it worked correctly. with iLO i checked server status in storage, network and ..., everything is normal. i searched for a solution but i couldn't find anything. and i don't know how to troubleshoot. nothing is installed yet.
why this happened and what should i do?

here is a image of where it is stuck:
[image: error]

Comment: Why CentOS 7.5 when there's a newer version (7.9) available? Also make sure you've updated BIOS to the latest version.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov  we need to install something on it and OS version it can not be upper than 7.5. i asked the infrastructure team and they said everything is up to date.

Comment: CentOS 7.5 has long been EOL'ed and contains a large number of vulnerabilities. There's a very little difference between 7.5 and 7.9 except for updated X.org and Mesa which shouldn't affect any software. At least try booting 7.9 to see if the issue is resolved, then we'll take it from there.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov so there is no way to troubleshoot when it is stuck like this?

Comment: Reading about RNG, you find that it uses a "[true random number generator (TRNG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator)" implemented in hardware to initialize the kernel's random number generator. If your server were harddisk-based, you could disable the RNG service or change its configuration. However, this doesn't work with a DVDROM, except by creating your own modified DVDROM. Remastering methods are documented, but not very simple for someone who has never done it. Perhaps something can or must be configured on the Proliant to enable/disable/modify the TRNG.

Comment: There was a bug in the hardware RNG daemon which was solved just two years ago and it manifested just like you're experiencing it. It was ostensibly resolved which means you either have to disable this service, or upgrade it to the latest version available in CentOS after an installation.

Comment: It successfully started the RNG daemon, that’s just the last thing that started.  It’s stuck somewhere in the boot.  It looks like it is stuck on the network startup?  I agree with @Artem S. Tashkinov, try a 7.9 ISO.  As soon as you install 7.5 and run “yum update” you will get all the packages in 7.9 anyway (plus more bug/security fixes)

Comment: That's the issue, it looks like the OP wants to run 7.5 without any updates because `yum update` will upgrade to 7.9 by default without asking any questions, so insisting on installing 7.5 becomes moot.